# Page ignoring template

Tags: craft3

One of my clients' sites is https://anovaworks.com/. The second section on the homepage looks like this:
[image: https://anovaworks.com/]

There's some small black text in the top left of the image that's coming from a matrix field.

It's supposed to look like this, and if you go to https://anovaworks.com/index.php or https://anovaworks.com/?, it looks correct:
[image: https://anovaworks.com/index.php]

I cannot figure out what's causing this. Anyone have any ideas?

Template code:

```
<section class="homepage-tagline">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell small-12 medium-7 large-5 circle-container">
        {# blue circle svg #}
        {% for matrix in entry.homepageTagline.all() %}
          <h2>{{ matrix.firstLine}}<br>{{ matrix.secondLine }}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
          <a href="{{ entry.homepageTaglineButtonLink.one().url }}"><button class="button">{{ entry.homepageTaglineButtonText }}</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not much info to go on here, can you share the template code for that div?

Comment: The container <div class="cell small-12 medium-7 large-5 circle-container"> is not showing up in the case where the circle does not appear, suggesting that there is some kind of routing issue and multiple templates. Make sure there are no routes and that Settings > Section specifies the correct path to your template

Comment: I don't have any routes, and the section is using the correct template.

Comment: There is definitely something going on in terms of the template that is being loaded. The <head> section of the page is different for the version that works. Which version of Craft are you running?

Comment: I'm on Craft 3.1.8.

Comment: If you remove the SVG like you did in your question, is it all ok? The error seems to come before your {# comment #} and since the only thing after `<div class="cell small-12 medium-7 large-5 circle-container">` is your SVG; it may lead to something.

Comment: @MaximeLafrenière I changed the SVG into an `<img>`, and it's still having the issue at https://anovaworks.com/, but the new `<img>` is showing just fine at https://anovaworks.com/index.php

Comment: Is the template code you provided verbatim, or are there some includes in the actual template? The strange thing is the HTML on the page that works shows the matrix content inside a div with a class of 'circle content', which does not appear in the code you printed above. That div, and it's parent div.circle, do not appear in the HTML for a page that exhibits the problem, so there are either two different templates or something happening with includes.

Comment: @RoiAgneta everything is in the source code (dont look at the inspector preview, but the code itself.

Comment: @JonWeedin look at my answer, its really your javascript that cause your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out! GoDaddy was adding some random JavaScript to my page because my client had purchased a "Search Engine Visibility" package from them. When I turned off that package inside GoDaddy, my page worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div class="cell small-12 medium-7 large-5 circle-container">` is well displayed in the source code, but not in the inspector; Try to remove and/or fix what interfere with this piece of HTML (JS?).

Edit: If I disable JavaScript on my browser, everything is fine on your site.

Comment: It appears that **jshint** (the last `<script>` tag in the `<head>`) is being injected into my site, but that's not in my template. I'm only loading Google Analytics, jquery, and a custom app.js; when I removed those three `<script>` tags from my _layout, it still had the same issue. Any idea on how to remove this random `<script>` that shouldn't be on my site?

Comment: You have no control on that JS? Is it hooked by some Craft tag, try to put your JS in the footer (or remove the `{{ head() }}` function for test purpose.